# Can I store a cardID from Stripe on Parse and remain PCI compliant?

Tags: parse-platform, stripe-payments, pci-compliance

I have an app that uses Parse as its backend, and has Stripe integration.  On Parse, I store a Stripe customer id on my User class, and I have a custom class that has a charge token associated with it, so that a customer can create a service request, and when a provider accepts and fulfills that request, they can have the charge be sent to their recipient id.

A user could cancel the service request, or a provider could show up to the user's property and find that the property is unserviceable for various reasons.  In this event, we have a cancellation fee that the users are charged.

I want to make sure that if the cancellation fee is charged, it gets charged to the same card that the user used to request the service.  I noticed that when I fetch all of the cards from a customer id, they always show up in the same order, but when I add a card, it doesn't always add it to the end of the array that gets returned when I fetch cards.  So, if I just stored the index of the card, a user could add a new card, and it would possibly take the place of the one that was being charged for the service.  If I charged a card based on the index for a cancellation, it could charge the incorrect card.  Would it be PCI compliant to store the cardID used to create the charge token on the Parse object that contains information about the service, so when I call my functions to create cancellation charges, I'm charging the same card?

Thanks for anyone who can provide some information on this.

Comment: There is a lot more to PCI compliance than whether you are storing a card number or ID. This isn't a programming question so talk to the experts: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/index.php

Comment: I understand there is a lot to PCI compliance. I'm asking about a particular thing, and it's a way that APIs return and take in information.  I think it's very programming related.

Comment: Your title is 'Can I store a card ID and remain compliant?' - that's clearly a question about compliance, not programming, so it's off topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The only sensitive data that you want to avoid handling is your customers' credit card number and CVC; other than that, you're welcome to store any other information on your local machines.
>
> As a good rule, you can store anything returned by our API. In particular, you would not have any issues storing the last four digits of your customer's card number or the expiration date for easy reference.

from: https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-information-can-i-safely-store-about-my-users-payment-information